# Specifying nodeSize for each node individually in D3.js tree layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, spacing

How do I set the nodeSize for the D3 tree layout for each node individually? In my case I have a tree containing nodes of varying sizes and setting `d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([300, 200]);` results in weird spacing when the width of nodes varies. nodeSize seems to be one of the few D3 functions which does not take a function as a parameter.
The closest thing I found was the separation function, but it does not really solve the problem.

Is there a way, or do I need to calculate the positions manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why didn't the separation function solve your problem?

You get two nodes as params to the separation function. If you set `nodeSize([1, 200])` and calculate the actual width of both nodes inside the separation function, you could add an appropriate separation.

```
.separation(function(a, b) {
  var totalWidth = a.width + b.width;
  return (totalWidth / 2) + 10;
})
```

Maybe you need a bit more to calculate the width, but without your code I can't guess how the width of your nodes gets calculated.